# Cassandra nodetool "compactionstats" meaning of displayed values

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I cannot find documentation on the "compactionstats":

While using `nodetool compactionstats`, what do the numerical values on the `completed` and `total` columns mean?
My column family has a total data size of about 360 GB but my compaction status displays:

```
pending tasks: 7
compaction type  keyspace   column family   completed      total           unit   progress
Compaction       Test       Message         161257707087   2475323941809   bytes  6.51%
```

While I see the "completed" increasing slowly (also the progress;-).

But how is this "total" computed? Why is it 2.5 TB when I have only 360 GB of data?

Answer (score 3):

You must have compression on.  `total` is the total number of uncompressed bytes comprising the set of sstables that are being compacted together.  If you grep the cassandra log file for lines containing `Compacting` you will find the sstables that are part of a compaction.  If you sum these sizes and multiply by the inverse of your compression ratio for the column family you will get pretty close to the total.  By default this can be a bit difficult to verify on a multi-core system because the number of simultaneous compactions defaults to the number of cores.

You can also verify this answer by looking at the code:

[AbstractionCompactionIterable](https://apache.googlesource.com/cassandra/+/863428c2b523695275897291d2da3de6f12dd0bd/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/AbstractCompactionIterable.java) - `getCompactionInfo()` uses the `bytesRead` and `totalBytes` fields from that class.  `totalBytes` is final and is computed in the constructor, by summing `getLengthInBytes()` from each file that is part of the compaction.

The scanners vary, but the length in bytes returned by [CompressedRandomAccessReader](https://apache.googlesource.com/cassandra/+/74f37b5a398fea0d60c5dc87124208a28580e8c3/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/compress/CompressedRandomAccessReader.java) is the uncompressed size of the file.